# Instantiating a X509Certificate object in C# which holds a private key as well

Tags: c#, openssl, private-key, x509certificate2, makecert

I'm trying to implement a secure TCP server and as the result I need to create an object of class `X509Certificate2` in order to authenticate the clients.

I believe such a certificate object should contain the private key (as well) in order to be able to decrypt incoming messages, isn't that true? Well no matter how I generate a certificate file, when I give its file address to `X509Certificate2`'s constructor the object's `HasPrivateKey` property is false and clients are not authenticated!

In the Microsoft's page on [how to use the `X509Certificate2` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx), in source code's comments it indicates that the certificate can be generated using `makecert` program like this:

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=CERT_SIGN_TEST_CERT" -b 01/01/2010 -e 01/01/2012 -sky exchange -ss my
```

In which `-pe` switch should include the private key in certificate but looking at the generated file I can tell that it does not do that.

Since I'm implementing this software in Ubuntu using Mono I thought I can use `openssl` instead. So following the instructions given in [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html) I created a private key and a public key. `X509Certificate2` class accepts the public key as if it was created by `makecert` command but not the private key (it throws an exception when it is constructed).

There is a [relatively old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437039a4/importing-an-openssl-created-self-signed-cert-into-a-x509certificate2-mono-ca) in SO which asks the same question but it has no accepted answer. And the two given ones suggest using two different formats for certificates, PKCS8 and PKCS12 while in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykwkw5f9.aspx) it is clearly said that `X509Certificate` make use of PKCS7!

Anyway I'm all confused. Has anyone ever been able to use `X509Certificate2` with a private key loaded? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An X509 certificate should only contain a public key.  It binds the public key to an identity and is signed.  [RFC 5280](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt) contains the details on X509 certificates.

However, the `X509Certificate2` object can contain a private key according to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx).

Also, a keystore, such as a PKCS12 keystore can contain a private key and a corresponding certificate.

PKCS7 is a specification for signing and encrypting messages.

PKCS8 is a specification for private keys.

See [PKCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS) for the differences between different PKCS standards.

The MSDN link above has some example C# code to encrypt and decrypt files.  It also has an example `makecert` command line to generate a certificate.  However this certificate and associated private key is stored in the Windows local user store, so I'm not sure if that will translate correctly to Ubuntu.

There is also some discussion in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471716/how-to-get-private-key-from-pkcs12-p12-file-using-c-sharp?rq=1) about using PKCS12 keystores to instantiate the `X509Certificate2` object and then to access the private key.  This might be the better way for you to accomplish your goal.  You can use openssl to generate a private key, a signed certificate, and import them into a PKCS12 keystore.  You can create a PKCS12 keystore using the commands [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html).  For example, create a text file (file.pem) containing both the PEM format of your private key and corresponding X509 certificate.  Then run this command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in file.pem -out file.p12 -name "My Certificate"
```

Also on the `makecert` documentation page, it says, "for testing purposes only".  So I wouldn't depend on those certificates for a production secure server.

Comment: Thanks for the post. Having read the differences among PKCSs, the wikipedia link and your post, it makes me wonder if `X509Certificate` class would ever be able to decrypt incoming messages as for that a private key is required. Yet it is used for implementing a secure server! Do you have any comments on that?

Comment: I've edited my answer a bit.  The MSDN documentation does seem to indicate an X509Certificate2 object (different than the X509Certificate object) CAN contain a private key.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to export a PKCS12 file using `openssl`, and `X509Certificate2` consumed it smoothly. Once it did the `HasPrivateKey` property was true.